# Access BIOS on Toshiba Satellite C55-A?

Tags: uefi, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite C55-A with Windows 8.1 Pro under UEFI. It originally came with Windows 8. But now the problem is I received Error Code 0x00000e9 and "Your PC needs to be repaired."

Well I can't access BIOS or anything to try to boot from my Windows 8.1 disc and I have no clue what else to do. I have tried everything under Startup Settings. Any ideas?

Comment: Why can you not access the bios?

Comment: Toshiba doesn't allow it in these newer PC's or they've changed how it is done

Comment: A quick google search provided me with the instructions for your exact model.  Getting your laptop to boot from any removable media with the new SecureBoot protocol is not trival, but your Windows 8.1 startup disk should work without any changes to the BIOS (unless it's a pirated copy...) since the boot from CD is the default first option for your laptop model unless you've changed it.

Comment: It must've been changed because I asked my Uncle to install it for me.

Comment: Lets try to keep this to one question per question. :)  I chopped this question down to be about getting into the BIOS. Once you've done that try the repairs you wanted to try, and if you still have problems come back and post new questions about those specific problems.

Answer (score 8):

From the Toshiba Forums: [Toshiba Satellite C55-A5310 - Bios Settings Key Combo](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/General-Troubleshooting/Toshiba-Satellite-C55-A5310-Bios-Settings-Key-Combo/td-p/518767)

> To access the BIOS or Boot Order screens on your new Windows 8 machine, Shutdown while pressing the Shift key. Hold down the F2 key (BIOS) or the F12 key (Boot Order) while pressing the Power key.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my Toshiba C55-C-1KZ, Just go to bios disable the security then go to change SC BOOT NOT UEFI. Trying windows 7 doesnt see the hdd but windows 8.1 is ok and easy, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold down shift F2 or Shift f12 when powering on the computer and when you see the Toshiba logo, let go and press down Shift f2 or f12 and BIOS screen will appear.

Comment: Windows 8 is different

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10

```
Hold down the F2 key (BIOS) or the F12 key (Boot Order) WHILE 
pressing the Power key. Don't wait for the slpash screen
```

Comment: This looks like it may be quoted material.  If so, please cite your source.

Comment: no I have the laptop in front of me .lol

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect everything. Flip the laptop over and remove the hard drive panel and  find the RTC battery (what we used to call the CMOS battery) and gently lift it with a small screwdriver to break the circuit, so to speak. After "breaking the circuit," reseat the battery and then power up. You will get a basic screen saying that the "RTC Battery is low, hit F2 to set time/date". This will get you into BIOS setup mode where you can change anything you wish.

Comment: Follow up for those confused. After "breaking the circuit", reseat the battery and then power up.

Comment: Instead of providing clarification to your answer with a comment, just edit your answer, and delete your answer.