# Windows 8.1 Pro Disc Blank Screen

Tags: windows-8.1

Resulting from the answer on this page: [Access BIOS on Toshiba Satellite C55-A?](https://superuser.com/questions/838235/access-bios-on-toshiba-satellite-c55-a) I started my laptop with Power-f12. Now, this works, or so it seems.

The laptop shows The Windows 8 logo and the spinner indicating it is loading. Then a black screen appears. I let it sit for a couple of hours but nothing happened. So what should I do at this point? Was there something I missed?

Comment: "The laptop shows The Windows 8 logo and the spinner indicating it is loading." Is this when trying to boot to the HDD or to the Windows 8.1 disk you mentioned in your other question?

Comment: Boot Windows 8 and get it to the Advanced Startup Options screen. One of the advanced start options will be to boot to VGA or low resolution mode. I wonder if the screen hasn't been picked up properly and is going out of the range for the graphics adapter.

Comment: @BigChris I will try that as soon as get my laptop back. It is currently a couple miles away. Thank you

Comment: @cʜι007 This is when I boot from the disc

Comment: @BigChris I can't set low resolution when trying to boot fro. The disc. The option is only available to the actual operating system